# glmnet coefficients differ between versions (2.0.16 vs 3.0.2)

Tags: r, machine-learning, glmnet, lasso-regression

I manage an internal code base that relies heavily upon the `glmnet` package. Upon upgrading to the newest version (`v3.0.2`) my unit tests started failing for the coefficients of a Cox model. The previous version of `glmnet` was `v2.0.16 (R 3.5.2)`. I am now running R `v3.6.2`.

I have noticed that there is a new `relax =` argument that appears to use un-regularized fits in the path and I'd imagine this *could* cause a slight difference in the fits, however the default is `relax = FALSE`, so I doubt that is the issue.

Below is a `reprex` based on the `mtcars` dataset, fitting 2 randomly chosen features and renaming two variables to `time` and `status` so as to allow fitting of a Cox model. A proper reprex comparison is difficult as it would require different R installations, but this should allow anyone to reproduce the issue.

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(glmnet)
dat <- mtcars %>%
    select(mpg, disp, status = vs, time = hp) %>%   # select 2 features; assign time & status
    mutate_at(1:2, ~ {
      log10(.x) %>% subtract(mean(.)) %>% divide_by(sd(.))   # center & scale
    }) %>% as.matrix()
glmnet(dat[, 1:2], dat[, 3:4], family = "cox", lambda = 0)$beta   # fit model
```

The result for `v3.0.2` is:

```
#> 2 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#>              s0
#> mpg   0.2293535
#> disp -1.8160387
```

The result for `v2.0.16` is:

```
#> 2 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#>              s0
#> mpg   0.2154324
#> disp -1.8172714
```

Have others noticed similar discrepancies? I am somewhat surprised not to have found anyone else bumping into this same issue. Am I going to have to update all my unit tests :(

Insights and/or explanations greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly too long for a comment:

- I reproduced your results on Ubuntu 16.04 (using `devtools::install_version()`, see below).
- 2.0-16 to 3.0-2 spans several releases (and several more internally labeled, unreleased versions): the [NEWS file](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/news/news.html) makes several references to `coxnet` (presumably the internal function called for `family="cox"`:

> - 2.0-20:
>
> - Fixed a bug in internal function coxnet.deviance to do with input pred, as well as saturated loglike (missing) and weights
> - added a coxgrad function for computing the gradient

> - 2.0-19:
>     Fixed a bug in coxnet to do with ties between death set and risk set

I would suggest using

```
devtools::install_version("glmnet",version=...,lib=<version-specific>)
```

to install every version from 2.0-16 to 3.0-2 inclusive, each in a separate library, to make it easy (via `library("glmnet", lib.loc=...`) to load different package versions and bisect to find the specific change. (The intermediate versions were unreleased, so you'll be jumping from 2.0-18 to 3.0.)

I'm guessing that one of those `coxnet` bug fixes is (intentionally or as a side effect) responsible for the changes.

If it were in an accessible git repository you could use `git bisect` with a local copy to automate the process (maybe not worth it for such a small number of changepoints, but it doesn't look like the development tree is available: there's a nice [pkgdown website](https://glmnet.stanford.edu/news/index.html) but I don't see any links to a version control system.

If you have a lot of time on your hands you can download all of the archived tarballs and hunt through them for changes ...

Comment: Thanks @benbolker! I had tried the `devtools::install_version()` route, but there were some system level Fortran dependencies on my MacOS that prevented me from jumping back and forth easily. But thank you so much for confirming my suspicion. As you say, this spans many versions and the `NEWS` you point to are likely the cause. Apparently you have more patience than I do scraping the `NEWS` logs! :) Looks like I'll be updating some unit tests. Thanks again for confirming!